# Drawing Networkx subgraph with Graphviz

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz

Given a network like the one below:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import graphviz

df = pd.DataFrame({'id_emp' : [13524791000109, 12053850000137, 4707821000113, 4707821000114, 1],
       'name_emp': ['Cristiano', 'Gaúcho', 'Fenômeno','Angelin', 'Souza'],
       'name_dep': ['Ronaldo','Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo', 'Bruno'],
       'weight_1': [8,9,10,11,12],
       'weight_2':[5,6,7,8,9] })

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()

G.add_nodes_from(df['id_emp'], bipartite = 0)
emp = [v for v in G.nodes if G.nodes[v]['bipartite'] == 0]

G.add_nodes_from(df['name_dep'], bipartite = 1)
dep = [v for v in G.nodes if G.nodes[v]['bipartite'] == 1]

G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[['name_dep', 'id_emp', 'weight_1']].values)
G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[['id_emp', 'name_dep', 'weight_2']].values)
edge_width = [a[2]['weight']//2 for a in G.edges(data=True)]

 d = graphviz.Digraph()

 for n in dep:
     d.node(str(n), color="#bfbf7f")

for n in emp:
    d.node(str(n), color="red")

for e in G.edges:
    d.edge(str(e[0]), str(e[1]))

d.attr(size='8')

# To display the graph on Jupyter
d
```

Using the networkx I can only plot a subgraph with the connections of the `Ronaldo` node with the following code:

```
dep = "Ronaldo"
lista_subset_graph = list(df[df["name_dep"] == dep]["id_emp"]) + [dep]
H = G.subgraph(lista_subset_graph)

nx.draw(H, style = "solid", with_labels = True)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.show()  # display
```

How can I draw the same subgraph, only with Ronaldo's connections, using Graphviz?

Answer (score 0):

To plot using graphviz, simply point the nodes and edges of the subroutine with networkx

```
dep = "Ronaldo"
lista_subset_graph = list(df[df["name_dep"] == dep]["id_emp"]) + [dep]
H = G.subgraph(lista_subset_graph)

dr = graphviz.Digraph(format='png')
for n in H.nodes():
    dr.node(str(n))

for n in H.edges():
    dr.edge(str(n[0]), str(n[1]))

dr
```